# Why always close Database connection?

Tags: c#, optimization, database-connection

If connecting to a database consumes a lot of resources, why should a database connection always be closed in your application if you have to open it again? Can I just make this connection available globally throughout my application so that other classes and methods can reuse it?

For example (in pseudo code):

```
public class PopulateGridViews()
{
    public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Database:DATABASE");
    conn.Open();

    void PopulateGrid1()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE1");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        // Populate Grid1
    }

    void PopulateGrid2()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE2");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        // Populate Grid2
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should not leave connections open.

**You should:**

1. Open connections as late as possible
2. Close connections as soon as possible

The connection itself is returned to the connection pool. Connections are a limited and relatively expensive resource. Any new connection you establish that has *exactly* the same connection string will be able to reuse the connection from the pool.

> We strongly recommend that you always
>   close the connection when you are
>   finished using it so that the
>   connection will be returned to the
>   pool. You can do this using either the
>   Close or Dispose methods of the
>   Connection object, or by opening all
>   connections inside a using statement
>   in C#, or a Using statement in Visual
>   Basic. Connections that are not
>   explicitly closed might not be added
>   or returned to the pool. For more
>   information, see using Statement (C#
>   Reference) or How to: Dispose of a
>   System Resource for Visual Basic.  [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).

You should appropriately wrap anything that implements `IDisposable` in a `using` statement block:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
     connection.Open();

     ...

     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: where should I put my catch if some errors occur during connection?

Comment: If you use the using block like @Mitch Wheat suggested, it will be closed automatically if there is an error.

Comment: So there is no way to determine to know the errors that occurred?

Comment: No.  You  can (and should) put your connection open and execution of the command inside a try statement.  You need to do this for the user experience anyway.  I am not advocating improper error handling.  I'm just saying that if you use the "using" command, the connection will be closed.  Personally, I always put the opening and command execution in a 'try' block and the connection.Close() call in the 'finally' block.

Comment: @yonan2236, you can put a try around if you like, for example higher up in the application. The using is like a try-finally, so the actual exception is not caught, it propagates on.

Comment: If a connection is made and then closed from France to Jamaica and it is in the connection pool, then is it correct to assume that no communication is needed other than to send data?

Answer (score 13):

Because (some) databases also hold open a connection until told by the calling app to close it.  If you get hundreds of calls to a database then it's sitting there with 100 open connections tying up resources.  It's not uncommon to have thousands or hundreds of thousands of calls to a database in a busy app, and sooner or later the DB performance will kill the app's performance.

It's really just common sense.  If you have a valid reason to keep it open, then do so.  If not, close it as soon as you're done with it.  But it's better to be in the good habit of closing the connections so that you don't just leave them open when you don't intend to.  It's a good habit like wearingyour seat belt or closing the refrigerator door when you're not getting food out.

This article states it well (even if it is a bit outdated):

http://www.bewebmaster.com/84.php

> A common problem among hosting
>   companies is that ASP websites do not
>   close the database connections after
>   they are opened. This is a basic step
>   that you should consider to be part of
>   mandatory code. If you do not close
>   your database connections, many
>   problems can occur like web pages
>   hanging, slow page loads, and more.
>
> Think of it as going through a door to
>   your house. Maybe the door will shut
>   by itself, but maybe it won't. If it
>   doesn't shut, who knows what will
>   happen. If you live in the country, a
>   bear could walk in. If you live in the
>   city, a mugger could walk in. Alright,
>   well maybe leaving a database
>   connection open won't lead to anything
>   that bad, but it will lead to a lot of
>   unnecessary headaches for both you and
>   your hosting company.

Comment: We had an application we inherited at work leak connections, it's not nice :( After a while the SQL Server stopped responding to new connections. It also meant that every other application stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear if you donot close the connection than it would consume your resource continuously and which would have overall impact on your apllication and it may also not be added or returned to the pool.