# sql server connection close issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why always close Database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111594/why-always-close-database-connection)

I usually use VS2010 and ASP.NET to develop my web projects, also my host providers often give me access to SQL Server 2008, I have a general question regarding connection close, should I always close my SQL connection after I'm done with SQL? what happens if I do NOT close my connection? is it harmful?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft strongly recommends that you always close the connection when you are finished using it so that the connection will be returned to the pool. You can do this using either the Close or Dispose methods of the Connection object, connections are released back into the pool when they are closed or disposed.

Read about [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get your appropriate answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111594/why-always-close-database-connection), thanks for your time.

Comment: thanks for your constructive replies, it really helped me

Comment: Well copied and pasted ... very constructive thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

if we don't close the connection , it wil lead to 
connection memory leakage.unless until application 
server/web server is shut down ,connection wil remain 
activate even though the user logs out .