# Trying to delete a record from my access database in visual basic studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

```
Private Function CreatePlayerAdapter(ByVal playerDBconnection As OleDbConnection) As OleDbDataAdapter
```

// Initiating instances for the function

```
    Dim dataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand
    Dim parameter As OleDbParameter
```

// establishing the string to tell where to delete record from and how to find the record i want.
// PlayerIDTextBox.Text is a text on a form that is populated from the database after selecting a list of name (this works correctly) // connection is already open and is directed to correct place

```
    Dim sql As String = "DELETE * FROM Players WHERE ID ='" & CInt(PlayerIDTextBox.Text) & "'"
    myCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, playerDBconnection)

    parameter = myCommand.Parameters.Add("ID", OleDbType.Char, 3, "ID")
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original

    dataAdapter.DeleteCommand = myCommand

    Return dataAdapter
End Function
```

// i call this function after executing a button click.
//ListPlayerComboBox.Text is populated with the names and needs it a name to fill PlayerIDTextBox.Text(works correctly)

```
Private Sub RemovePlayerButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RemovePlayerButton.Click

        If ListPlayerComboBox.Text = " " Then
            MsgBox("Please Select a Player.")
    Else


        Me.CreatePlayerAdapter(playerDBConnection)

        End If


End Sub
```

// no errors occur. However, nothing is done in the database. help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notes:**

1)Never leave your `OleDbConnection Open`. Only allow it to be opened when you actually need it. This will save you from a lot of headaches later on. The reasons why can be found on [following stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111594/why-always-close-database-connection).

2) There is no reason to return an `OleDbDataAdapter` if you don't intend on using it.

3) Use your parameters correctly : see below example2

4) Keep in mind that there are some `restricted keywords` in `Access`. Luckely for you `ID` isn't one. The restrictedKeywords can be found here: [Keywords](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/286335)

I'm probably missing some further points here. Anyone should be free to add em.

---

Why not adjust your `Function CreatePlayerAdapter` to the following:

1) Without parameters

```
Private Sub CreatePlayerAdapter(ByVal playerDBconnection As OleDbConnection) 

    Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand

    Dim sql As String = "DELETE * FROM Players WHERE ID =" & CInt(PlayerIDTextBox.Text) 
    myCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, playerDBconnection)

    playerDBconnection.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    playerDBconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

2) With parameters

```
Private Sub CreatePlayerAdapter(ByVal playerDBconnection As OleDbConnection) 

    Dim myCommand As OleDbCommand

    Dim sql As String = "DELETE * FROM Players WHERE ID = @playerId"
    myCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, playerDBconnection)


    Dim param As New OleDb.OleDbParameter(@playerId", CInt(PlayerIDTextBox.Text))
    myCommand.Add(param)

    playerDBconnection.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    playerDBconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

The method `ExecuteNonQuery executes the query` passed to the command `on the specified OleDbConnection` and returns the number of rows affected. More info [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Well, you have good points here, but why forgetting the (I wish to be) mandatory "USE A PARAMETERIZED QUERY" one?

Comment: @Steve was adding it. give me a second. So much wrong here

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited my code to utilize no parameters and looks like number 1 in your reply, but now i get a "data type mismatch in criteria expression" error. Any idea?

Comment: Is `ID`in your database if of type Integer (Number) or String(Text)?

Comment: @N55PEC ID is of type Integer(Number). It is AutoNumber though. I researched and saw removing the apostrophes from the sql string works, but it still did not work. Again, my code looks just like number 1 and your comment above.

Comment: `data type mismatch in criteria expression`usually means that you're comparing to the wrong type of data. Like in this case your trying to compare a string with an Integer. I've modified the example in the first solution to exclude the `'`. If you still encouter a problem, feel free post a comment.

Comment: @N55PEC ok, the data type mismatch error went away. There are no errors at all and it still will not delete from the database. I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: That can only signify 1 thing: The value contained in `PlayerIDTextBox.Text` has no corresponding `ID` in the database.