# Not working login with roles (web forms)

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want create a authentication module with 3 roles in asp.net web forms.
I created a simple database with one table user (id, login, password, role).
I have a 3 roles: user, user2 and admin.
I would like to users with specific roles were redirected to individual pages.

Login.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication6
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static string DatabaseConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbtestConnectionStrings"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection _connection= new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString);


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    }

    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var comm = new SqlCommand("select * from user where login=@login and password=@password", _connection);

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", LoginUser.UserName);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", LoginUser.Password);

            _connection.Open();

            var rd = comm.ExecuteReader(); 
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    Session["UserName"] = rd["login"].ToString();
                    string role = rd["role"].ToString();
                    if (role == "user") Response.Redirect("User/User.aspx");
                    else if (role == "user2") Response.Redirect("User2/User.aspx");
                    else Response.Redirect("Admin/Admin.aspx"); 
                }
            }

            else
            {
                LoginUser.FailureText = "ERROR";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Response.Write(exception.StackTrace);
        }
        }         
    }
}
```

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHIzx.png)

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbtestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.csdl|res://*/DataModel.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ROG-KOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=dbtest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="dbtestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ROG-KOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbtest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did u tried debugging? what is happening ..any error?

Comment: ur connection is giving error. Please check the connection string

Comment: In Server Explorer I have Data Connection --> dbtestConnectionString. In Modify Connection is button Test Connection: "Test Connection Succeeded".
I can show my web.config if you want.

Comment: can u debug the app and check which line is throwing the error?

Comment: I`ve never used debugger, how should i do it?
At the end of error in picture result is something like that:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at WebApplication6.Login.LoginButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Users\ROG\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication6\WebApplication6\Login.aspx.cs:line 33

Comment: [How to debug]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_debugging.htm

Comment: Not related to your question, but you forgot to close your Open Connection. refer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111594/why-always-close-database-connection)

Comment: Yes but I think you need to close it inside "finally"  `
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
            rd.Close();
            _connection.Close();
            }` Sorry if this is not related to your question and will be my last  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can see two flaws

1. User is a keyword and you are using that as a table name
2. When assigning parameter value you are specifiying `@`

try below code

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select login,role from [user] where login=@login and password=@password", _connection);

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", LoginUser.UserName);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", LoginUser.Password);

            _connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader(); 
            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    Session["UserName"] = rd[0].ToString();
                    string role = rd[1].ToString();
                    if (role == "user") Response.Redirect("User/User.aspx");
                    else if (role == "user2") Response.Redirect("User2/User.aspx");
                    else Response.Redirect("Admin/Admin.aspx"); 
                }
            }

            else
            {
                LoginUser.FailureText = "ERROR";
            }
rd.Close();
_connection.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Response.Write(exception.StackTrace);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Now its work, but everything what i type in login and password redirects me to Admin.aspx

Comment: can you post the table column name and values?

Comment: Columns: ID, login, password, role.
Values: 1,user,pass,user; 2,user2,pass2,user2; 3,admin,pass,admin

Comment: can u debug and check what is the value coming in role?

Comment: Role - value null, type string

Comment: Role still in debugger is null

Comment: @Risksec7 edited answer. Please check..also debugging check the values passing to login and password parameter too..and check how many rows it return to data reader.

Comment: I changed to test "Session["UserName"] = rd[0].ToString()" to "string name = rd[0].ToString()" and value is still null. comm.Parameters.AddWithValue return correctly login and password. Now i trying to find how many rows return to data reader 

@edit when i debug this line "var rd = comm.ExecuteReader()" rd has value null.

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: The query executing and rd  had null value..then how it entering the loop?

Comment: did u changed var rd to sqldatareader rd ..like in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like that:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var comm = new SqlCommand("select login,role from [user] where login=@login and password=@password", _connection);

                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", LoginUser.UserName);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", LoginUser.Password);

                _connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        Session["UserName"] = rd[0].ToString();
                        string role = rd[1].ToString();

                        if (role == "user") Response.Redirect("User/User.aspx");
                        else if (role == "user2") Response.Redirect("User2/User.aspx");
                        else Response.Redirect("Admin/Admin.aspx");


                    }
                }


                else
                {
                    LoginUser.FailureText = "ERROR";
                }
                rd.Close();
                _connection.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Response.Write(exception.StackTrace);
                Label1.Text = exception.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: don't add ur code as answer.edit the question and post it there..also in parameter still i can see '@'..it is not like i mentioned in answer

Comment: With '@" and without this result is the same.
Any ideas?

Comment: it should be with @..nothing wrong in the code..some data issue it seems

Comment: Why Session["UserName"] = rd[0].ToString work correctly, but string role = rd[1].ToString() not ?