# i got an da.Fill(ds) error for my shopping card project in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

public partial class AddToCart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;
            dt.Columns.Add("sno");
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductID");
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductImage");
            dt.Columns.Add("Cost");
            dt.Columns.Add("TotalCost");

```
        if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["Buyitems"] == null)
            {

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                String mycon = "Data Source=DESKTOP-8C66I6S/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=haritiShopping;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(mycon);
                String myquery = "select * from productdetail where ProductID=" + Request.QueryString["id"];
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = myquery;
                cmd.Connection = scon;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dr["sno"] = 1;
                dr["ProductID"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductID"].ToString();
                dr["ProductName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductName"].ToString();
                dr["ProductImage"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductImage"].ToString();
                dr["Price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Session["buyitems"] = dt;
            }
            else
            {

                dt = (DataTable)Session["buyitems"];
                int sr;
                sr = dt.Rows.Count;

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                String mycon = "Data Source=DESKTOP-8C66I6S/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=haritiShopping;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(mycon);
                String myquery = "select * from productdetail where ProductID=" + Request.QueryString["id"];
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = myquery;
                cmd.Connection = scon;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dr["sno"] = sr + 1;
                dr["ProductID"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductID"].ToString();
                dr["ProductName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductName"].ToString();
                dr["ProductImage"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductImage"].ToString();
                dr["Price"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Price"].ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                Session["buyitems"] = dt;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["buyitems"];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Welcom @Meti Rs. Any more information? Just codes doesn't enough. You should describe what problem you met and what you want.

Comment: add error details

Comment: when i click on the add to card button it's show me this and page still trying to load

da.Fill(ds);

sqlExeption was unhandled by user code
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Update your `connection string` like below. You are missing to specify whether you want to use `Windows Authentication` or `User Id` & `Password`.

**For `Windows Authentication`** use `Integrated Security=SSPI` as below :

```
String mycon = "Data Source=DESKTOP-8C66I6S/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=haritiShopping;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

**For Authentication with `User Id` & `Password`** add `User Id` & `Password` as below. Use original `user id` and `password`. I have taken `sa` for example. :

```
String mycon = "Data Source=DESKTOP-8C66I6S/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=haritiShopping;Integrated Security=True;user id=sa;password=sa";
```

Also you need to open connection with

```
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(mycon);
scon.Open(); //Open connection
```

P.S. It is always recommended to `Close` connection too. Add `scon.Open();` after `da.Fill(ds);` line. [Why always close Database connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111594/why-always-close-database-connection)
.

```
da.Fill(ds);
scon.Close(); //Close connection
```

Comment: the first one did not worked still getting the same error

Comment: Did you add `scon.Open();` to open connection? It will required in both cases.

Comment: How do you connect with you database from `ssms`? With windows authentication or with userid and password?

Comment: with windows authentication

Comment: Then it should work. Please check if there is any typing mistake for `data source` or `initial catalog` names?